# asp.net core custom authentication with generated token without session

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm building a website with asp.net core and I had the idea to let my users log in as follows:

1. Let the user enter a discord tag (in the more general case, you could use an email address instead)
2. Send a token to the given discord user (or email address)
3. Let the user enter the token that was sent to them

I've read about asp.net core's cookie login system, but I have trouble applying it with this authentication sequence and I am not sure if this is a safe way to log in.
My first thought was to use sessions. I'd generate a random token and store it together with the given discord tag in a session and I'd wait for the user to provide the token and compare. However, I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that it's not safe to store sensitive data in a session and on top of that, I read that the use of a session gives the app a big performance penalty, so I feel like using sessions is not the right approach.

So my question is like this: **Can I perform this authentication sequence without a session?**

The only other way I know to keep data between requests is to use a cookie, but I know that it's not secure at all to keep login data in a cookie, even if it's encrypted, because users can change their cookies locally.

My idea with cookies was to create a json string with the username, the generated token and a timestamp and encrypt it server side with a symmetric encryption algorithm. Then when the user sends their token, I can decrypt the cookie and read the discord user and the expected token and see if it has timed out or not with the timestamp. But because cookies are stored client side, I'm not sure if this is secure.

*Here's some context, just in case*:
I'm building a small web based game and I want it to be both controllable throught the website and through discord. I somehow have to know from a requester which discord account belongs to them, so I want them to use their discord tag as a username to log in. I figured for a small game like this, it would be overkill to force people to make an account if they're only using it a few times, so I just want to quickly verify that the discord name they use is the one that they own.

I am not very familiar with authentication, so I don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction or if I'm doing it completely wrong.

Comment: you can do this **without** cookie and session. The answer is in your description --- you can create a token at server side using user's discord and encrypt using symmetric algo. When user sends the token using query parameter or post body then you can decrypt it. At client side the token can be stored in the local session.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, I should create a single string with the token and the username and encrypt it and store it in the client's local session? Then the user enters the token and sends both the token and the encrypted string from the local session to the server?

Comment: `But because cookies are stored client side, I'm not sure if this is secure.` storing the auth token in encrypted form in cookie is the standard approach. Almost every single website does this.